# Eclipse Galileo connection with MySQL - unable to connect some databases

Tags: mysql, eclipse

I am using Eclipse Galileo on Windows 7. I opened Database Connection perspective, added the mysql-connector-5.0.8 jar. The driver is able to connect the **test** database (one of the default databases in MySQL), but it is not able to connect the newly created database **bank**.

Using **select user()**, I found the current user to be root. The root can access the database without password(through JDBC) but mysql console asks for a password.

So, When trying to connect to my bank database , I get the following:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'bank'
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:2985)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:885)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.secureAuth411(MysqlIO.java:3421)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1247)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:2775)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:1555)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.createConnection(JDBCConnection.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.drivers.jdbc.JDBCConnection.open(JDBCConnection.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.mysql.connection.JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(JDBCMySQLConnectionFactory.java:28)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:355)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Comment: Could you try it with the latest Eclipse Luna, and a DTP 1.1.12 (http://wiki.eclipse.org/index.php/Data_Tools_Platform_Project#DTP_1.12_.28.22Luna.22.29_Information)

Comment: Actually I could, but I have a plugin that is compatible only with this version of Eclipse. So I would like to stick on with it